# New width from aspect ratio on child isn't respected in parent

Tags: css, aspect-ratio

I have a container containing some text, as well as a box positioned to the right. I would like for this box's width and height to be the same, and for both to be equal to the container's total height. I thought I could achieve this by using CSS's built-in `aspect ratio`. This works for the button, but the button's container doesn't seem to expand to fit the child's width, even when the button's container's width is set to `fit-content`.

```css
.container {
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  column-gap: 8px;
  width: fit-content;
}
.text {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
.button_container {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid green;
  width: fit-content;
}
.button {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;

  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 100%;
  aspect-ratio: 1 / 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="text">
    Hello, World!<br/>Nice day!
  </div>
  <div class="button_container">
    <div class="button">
      <svg width="16" height="16" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
        <path d="M10,1.445c-4.726,0-8.555,3.829-8.555,8.555c0,4.725,3.829,8.555,8.555,8.555c4.725,0,8.555-3.83,8.555-8.555C18.555,5.274,14.725,1.445,10,1.445 M10,17.654c-4.221,0-7.654-3.434-7.654-7.654c0-4.221,3.433-7.654,7.654-7.654c4.222,0,7.654,3.433,7.654,7.654C17.654,14.221,14.222,17.654,10,17.654 M14.39,10c0,0.248-0.203,0.45-0.45,0.45H6.06c-0.248,0-0.45-0.203-0.45-0.45s0.203-0.45,0.45-0.45h7.879C14.187,9.55,14.39,9.752,14.39,10 M14.39,12.702c0,0.247-0.203,0.449-0.45,0.449H6.06c-0.248,0-0.45-0.202-0.45-0.449c0-0.248,0.203-0.451,0.45-0.451h7.879C14.187,12.251,14.39,12.454,14.39,12.702 M14.39,7.298c0,0.248-0.203,0.45-0.45,0.45H6.06c-0.248,0-0.45-0.203-0.45-0.45s0.203-0.45,0.45-0.45h7.879C14.187,6.848,14.39,7.051,14.39,7.298"></path>
      </svg>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm looking for pure CSS solutions to the issue.

Answer (score 0):

define a fixed width for the button. for example `width: 50px;`

```css
.container {
    border: 1px solid red;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    column-gap: 8px;
    width: fit-content;
  }
  .text {
    border: 1px solid blue;
  }
  .button_container {
    display: flex;
    border: 1px solid green;
    width: fit-content;
    
  }
  .button {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
  
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 100%;
    width: 50px;
    aspect-ratio: 1 / 1;
  }
```

```html
  <div class="container">
    <div class="text">
      Hello, World!<br/>Nice day!
    </div>
    <div class="button_container">
      <div class="button">
        <svg width="16" height="16" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
          <path d="M10,1.445c-4.726,0-8.555,3.829-8.555,8.555c0,4.725,3.829,8.555,8.555,8.555c4.725,0,8.555-3.83,8.555-8.555C18.555,5.274,14.725,1.445,10,1.445 M10,17.654c-4.221,0-7.654-3.434-7.654-7.654c0-4.221,3.433-7.654,7.654-7.654c4.222,0,7.654,3.433,7.654,7.654C17.654,14.221,14.222,17.654,10,17.654 M14.39,10c0,0.248-0.203,0.45-0.45,0.45H6.06c-0.248,0-0.45-0.203-0.45-0.45s0.203-0.45,0.45-0.45h7.879C14.187,9.55,14.39,9.752,14.39,10 M14.39,12.702c0,0.247-0.203,0.449-0.45,0.449H6.06c-0.248,0-0.45-0.202-0.45-0.449c0-0.248,0.203-0.451,0.45-0.451h7.879C14.187,12.251,14.39,12.454,14.39,12.702 M14.39,7.298c0,0.248-0.203,0.45-0.45,0.45H6.06c-0.248,0-0.45-0.203-0.45-0.45s0.203-0.45,0.45-0.45h7.879C14.187,6.848,14.39,7.051,14.39,7.298"></path>
        </svg>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: This does not achieve what I'm attempting. I wish for the box height to be the same as the container height. Your example increases the container height in the process. It would also not account for differences in height, for example from different fonts.